# is there any plugin to make kind of HuffPost image gallery for Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, responsive-design

Something like this

http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/12/31/animals-photos-of-the-year_n_4510716.html

with the little caption and even the little pointed lines that divides each pic.
Im working right now with Bootstramp 3 for Drupal and I wish to make it responsive too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Marked to close because off-topic because you are requesting suggestion for a tool. Note that such a quesion may be more appropriate on http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply create a new content type with an image field and use the body field for the caption. To render a page with images and captions you can either use the core taxonomy module, or you could build a custom view using the [views module](https://drupal.org/project/views).

Comment: Thank you very much, I did it and works, views module is amazing.